# Download file from Onedrive using API call

Tags: java, onedrive

I am trying to download files from onedrive which is shared by one organization using API in java.

The URL is like this:

```
https://organization_name-my.sharepoint.com/personal/name/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?originalPath=HR0cHM6Ly93b3JsZGhl...
```

I am able to download files manually.

But how can I achieve it by using Onedrive API call?